# Android profiler doesn't show fragment lifecycle

Tags: android, android-studio, profiler, android-profiler

Android community,

I just started using the `Android` `profiler` tool using the `Android Studio IDE`, but I can't see the life cycle fragments as you can see in the screenshot below:

[image]

I can just see the life cycle of activities

Can anyone help me in this case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess the problem is related to the SDK version of the Android phone because when I upgraded my phone's Android system to Android 8 the issue is no longer reproducible, 
Hope this answer helpful